# Oracle SQL: How to join tables containing ALL / Wildcard values?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, conditional-statements

I hope you can help me with the following :-)

Let's make it simple:
I have  table_A containing

```
COUNTRY, ACCOUNT, PRODUCT AND ORIGIN
```

and table_B containing

```
COUNTRY, ACCOUNT, PRODUCT, ORIGIN and TARIFF
```

My issue is that each column of table_B, except COUNTRY, can contain a "ALL" value, which means that the tariff applies to all accounts or product or origin.
See image...

[image: Example of Table_b]

How to use conditional join to use or skip join based on the 'ALL' values?
To get the tariff for Table_A data??

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't link images. Edit your request and copy and paste the table as text please.

Comment: So for an A record you want the tariff from B. What if there are multiple tariffs matching? Do you want to select all matching tarrffs or only one? If only one: which?

Comment: Please provide sample data for `A` and expected results.  What happens when multiple rows match?

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND`, `OR`, and parentheses in your `WHERE` clause.

```
select *
from table_a a
join table_b b on a.country = b.country
               and (a.account = b.account or b.account = 'ALL')
               and (a.product = b.product or b.product = 'ALL')
               and (a.origin  = b.origin  or b.origin  = 'ALL');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help :

```
SELECT A.*, B.TARIFF 
FROM table_A A, table_B B
    WHERE  ( B.COUNTRY = 'ALL' OR (B.COUNTRY = A.COUNTRY) )
    AND    ( B.ACCOUNT = 'ALL' OR (B.ACCOUNT = A.ACCOUNT) )
    AND    ( B.PRODUCT = 'ALL' OR (B.PRODUCT = A.PRODUCT) )
    AND    ( B.ORIGIN  = 'ALL' OR (B.ORIGIN  = A.ORIGIN ) )
```

Then it all depends of how are your tables defined (primary keys, unique keys..). Meaning, depending on tables stucture and data, you may have some duplicate tarifs for a single record from table_A.

Comment: You shouldn't use comma-separated joins. They have been made redundant in the SQL standard in 1992 for a reason. Use proper joins instead (`FROM table_A A JOIN table_B B ON ...`).